# How to switch between active docker machine on window

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am window user and working fine with the docker on default machine. I can build images and run it perfectly. But now I have scenario where I have to run two docker-machine parallel.

I have created new docker machine from following command:

**docker-machine create --driver virtualbox NAMEOFNEWMACHINE**

Now when I run **docker-machine ls** I can see there is two docker machine running.

Then I run **docker-machine ip** so it gives me the IP of default machine so basically I am not able to switch from default to new dev machine on docker.

I have read docker docs & I run commands which they mentioned to switch the machine

**eval "$(docker-machine env NAMEOFNEWMACHINE)"**

**docker-machine env NAMEOFNEWMACHINE**

but after running above command it still shows me default machine ip, Therefor I cannot build my image on new machine

I am pretty new to docker so is there anyone who can help me in how to run two docker machine parallel?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `docker-machine ip <name of the new machine>`? You know you can run multiple containers in a single docker machine, right?

Comment: Hi Yamin - can you describe why you need to run two docker-machines in parallel? That's not the standard way of running docker.

Comment: I don't think he means two _docker-machines_ Vince, he just means two machines under the control of docker-machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem on windows 7. Solved it by setting the windows DOCKER_HOST environment variable. Check your machine ip (docker-machine ls) and use the complete ip in the command:
SET DOCKER_HOST=